# Sails collection add/remove is very slow

Tags: sails.js

I am playing around with a little cardgame backend in Sails Framework - just for fun, and to get to now the framework.

I ran in to a problem when using collection on a model - don't know if i use it wrong or so - but its really slow - and don't get why.

simple example:

```
// models / Deck.js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    game : {
      model : 'game'
    },
    cards : {
      collection : 'card'
    },
  },

  newDeck : function(game_id, callback) {
    // 52 Cards
    Card.find({}).exec(function(err, results) {
        Deck.create({game : game.id}).exec(function(err, deck) {

          while(cards.length) {
            deck.cards.add(cards.pop());
          }
          deck.save(function(err, deck) {
            if(err) callback(err);
            callback(null, deck);
          });

        });
    }
}
```

When I call the newDeck function it takes round 5 to 10 sec. to finish - its all in the .save() function, the problem is, if I comment this out its done under 1 sec.

I another example i remove just ONE record, and that also take about 5-6 sec.

```
deck.cards.remove(card.id)
    deck.save(function(err, deck){
})
```

Am I doing something wrong .??
I have tried to create 52 records in another example and this takes under 1 sec. - can't figure out what i do wrong.

Comment: I tried CLEAR up the DB and now the save function only takes about 1 sec. but after filling in some decks - about 20 or so - it slows down again! So my test tells me that more decks with cards slows down the whole system - is this wired?

Comment: Hey, which DB provider are you using? If you're using 'sails-disk' it might be worth checking if it's better when using a proper db (like mysql), not sure how much data do you have. See config/connections.js for details.

Comment: I'm only developing - so I use the default that comes with Sails-- but can't understand why it is so dam slow to add some relations- it don't make sense - I think there is about 500 rows in that table, and i takes about 5 sec. to insert 52 new rows..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that if you have any associations on the model, they will be populated when saving.

To prevent that, use:

```
.save({ populate: false }, function() {})
```

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/save